# Display product variations on same row

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm having trouble displaying variations on the single product page in woocommerce. I would like to show the product variations on the same row and not separate, like the attached pic.

[image]

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Thankful for all the help I can get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this css code

```
.woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations tbody tr,.woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations tbody td {
    width: 50% !important;
    display: block;
}
.woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations tbody tr{display:inline-block;float:left;}
```

Try this , then let me know the result.
Thanks

Comment: Is there any easy way to add a custom link under the "Size" drop down to show "Size guide"?